# Rspec for checking of a number

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a ruby newbie, I have managed to pull out the code for ruby but writing rspecs for them seems problematic. It's hard to understand the way to write rspecs even after reading few tutorials. Someone please help me to write for an input method then I would try to refactor it for the rest.

RB file:

```
module RubyOperations
  class Operations
    def input(num)
      RubyOperations.log('Enter a number:[Between 1 to 10]',:BOTH)
      num = Integer(gets.chomp)
      raise StandardError if num <= 0 || num > 10
      return num
    rescue StandardError, ArgumentError => e
      RubyOperations.log(e,:ERROR)
    end
  end
end
```

RSPEC:

```
describe 'RubyOperations' do
  describe 'Operations' do
    describe '.input' do
      context 'when number is provided' do
        it 'returns the number provided' do
          expect(RubyOperations.input(num)).to eq(Integer)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look to [`RSpec Type Matchers`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers), it might help you for checking the "kind of object".

Comment: Thank you..Will look into it @SebastianPalma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with code that you have shared:

1) In the `Operations` class, the method `input` receives an argument which is not used anywhere because of this line: `num = Integer(gets.chomp)`. Basically `gets` is the method that waits for user input, and the assignment `num = ...` overrides the value of argument (`num`) that is passed into the method, hence it is pointless to pass `num` argument into the method.

2) In your spec sample you call `input` method on `RubyOperations` module, while the `input` lives in class `Operations` under namespace `RubyOperations`. Also method `input` is not a class method but instance method. So proper method call would be: `RubyOperations::Operations.new.input(5)`

3) To run a spec for `input` method you would need to stub user input. RSpec-mocks gem can help you with that - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks. It has `allow` stub method: `allow(object).to receive(:gets) { "5" }`

The whole sample will be:

```
it 'returns the number provided' do
  # instantiate object that we will test
  subject = RubyOperations::Operations.new

  # we stub method 'gets' and whenever it is called we return string "5"
  allow(subject).to receive(:gets) { "5" } 

  # we call method input with argument 1, the argument 1 is pointless as described in point 1) and can be omitted
  expect(subject.input(1)).to eq(5)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the class of the output of the method to equal integer

```
require 'ruby_final_operations'
  describe 'RubyOperations' do
    describe 'Operations' do
      describe '.input' do
        context 'when number is provided' do
          it 'returns the number provided' do
            expect(RubyOperations.input(num).class).to eq(Integer)
            (or)
            expect(RubyOperations.input(num)).to be_a_kind_of(Integer) 
          end
         end
        end
       end
      end
```

And whenever you write rspec keep in mind

If the method for which you are writing rspec deals with manipulations in your db then check if db is manipulated or not

Or if you are writing rspec for any methods which returns an object then procced like this

if a method is defined like

```
def square_of_a_number(num)
 num*num
end
```

Then write rspec like this

```
it 'returns square of a number' do
  expect(square_of_a_number(2).to eq(4)   
end
```

For any methods that you know the output of a method will be that then hardcode the input or user Faker gem for input of the method expect the expected result of that method

Comment: this is the error I faced.NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `num' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::RubyOperations::Operations::Input::WhenNumberIsPro
vided:0x0000000003844038>

Comment: Have you defined num before in your spec file?

Comment: You need to declare the num variable before you pass it as an argument. Please declare the num or pass an hard coded value to that method